# I'm looking to play with the unique R/C cars only available in the demo versions — How can I do this?

Tags: pc, re-volt

[Re-Volt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-Volt) has different demo versions which have different, unique R/C cars only available in each version (and not available in the full version). I would like to try those unique cars.

Example of a unique car in a demo version ('Gamespot' demo version):

[image]
The car at the right is the unique "Gamespot" car.

---

Here are the unique cars and the demo versions that I'm looking for:

**Demo name — Version — Unique Car**

PCXL (PC Accelerator) — v0.01pcxl — [PC Accelerator](http://revolt.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Accelerator_(car)) (grey, based on the 'Aquasonic' R/C car)

RIVATNT2 (Nvidia Corp) — v0.01nvidia — [RIVATNT2](http://revolt.wikia.com/wiki/Riva_TNT2_(car)#Additional_Informations) (green or blue, based on the 'Aquasonic' R/C car)

Gamecenter — v0.01gamecenter — Gamecenter (red, based on the 'Aquasonic' R/C car)

Creative (Creative Labs Ltd.) — v0.01creativelabs — unknown

McDonalds (Ziff Davis Media) — v0.01ziffdavis — unknown

Note: The Re-Volt Wiki lists [some of the demo versions](http://revolt.wikia.com/wiki/Demos#Demo_Differences), but [it is incomplete](http://revolt.wikia.com/wiki/Demos#Trivia).

**I'm looking to get the unique RC cars ony available in the demo versions - how can I do this, or can anyone point me to where I can get these demo versions?**

Comment: who's "us" actually?

Comment: @Samuele Mattiuzzo, re-volt wikia

Comment: Hey, Allan.  I've re-worded your question a bit.  It might change the intent of what you were looking for, though.  If you disagree, feel free to roll it back, but from the looks of things, your original question was gathering close votes.

Comment: @fbueckert: they are actually asking about demo files, not how to use hidden cars.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo I'm well aware; I'm trying to salvage the question, rather than just closing and deleting it.

Comment: @fbueckert we posted comments togheter. yours makes sense actually :)

Comment: @fbueckert If salvaging means completely changing the question and its intent, you might as well not bother.

Comment: Since when was "please help me find some links in the internet" a valid question?

Comment: @JeffMercado The answer does not necessarily have to be a link. It could say that "*this demo version was included in the CD of this magazine/product/etc...*", or maybe "*someone has modded this car to be playable in the full version...*", etc.

Comment: @Allan This is not the place to ask people to upload files for you.